# Is it possible to dynamically load a class and use it as a type?

Tags: java, classloader, instantiation

I am trying to make a code to dynamically load a class and use it to create new instances and to run casts. I can make an instance from the newly loaded class using this method: `myClass.newInstance();`. But I cannot use it as a type. For example: `myClass myObj = new myClass();` It doesn't work. Is it possible to perform somehow?

This is the code I was trying to make:

```
URL classUrl;
classUrl = new URL("file:///C:/classes/");
URL[] classUrls = { classUrl };
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
Class c = ucl.loadClass("Operation");
Class MyIn = ucl.loadClass("MyInter"); 
Object o = c.newInstance(); //IT WORKS
System.out.println(((MyIn) o).sum(2, 4)); //IT DOES NOT WORK. Message: MyIn cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: Are you asking why you can't use the class at compile-time, when you've loaded it after compile time?

Comment: You are right but I would like a way to do it dynamically, loading MyIn dynamically instead putting it into the project

Comment: `MyIn` in your code is a variable name and you later on try to cast `o` to the interface type `MyIn` - note the same characters here! Change the name of the variable `MyIn` to something more Java typical like `myIn`. You could also try to cast o to an instance of `MyIn` using: `MyIn instance = MyIn.getClass().cast(o);` and then use it in your application as any other none dynamically loaded instance of `MyIn`

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't know MyIn at compile time, you need to use reflection not only to instantiate the class, as you do, but also to call methods.

Something along the lines of:

```
MyIn.getDeclaredMethod("sum",Integer.TYPE,Integer.TYPE).invoke(o,2,4);
```

See for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: You can call its methods directly if they're in an interface that's both known at compile time and implemented by the dynamically loaded class.

Comment: MyIn is a inteface that I am trying to load. That's why I am trying to do a cast on o. The internface has an declaration of the method 'sum'. Running the line you gave me, it displays a new error: Caught exception : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: MyEx.sum()

Comment: See the API for getDeclaredMethod, needs parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use a class at compile-time that you load later at run-time.

However, you can work directly through one or more ***interfaces*** implemented by the loaded classes. Typically the interfaces themselves are included in the compile-time classpath of both the loading code and the loaded code.

The shared interfaces define the expected interaction at compile-time. The loaded code defines a behavior at run-time.

For example, you could load this dynamically loaded class:

```
public class Operation implements MyInterface { ... }
```

And then interact with it through a shared interface:

```
Class c = ucl.loadClass("mypackage.Operation");
Object o = c.newInstance(); //IT WORKS
MyInterface operation = (MyInterface) o;
```

Now you can interact directly with the methods through the shared interface.

```
System.out.println( operation.sum(2, 4) );
```

**Constructors**

> For example: myClass myObj = new myClass(); It doesn't work. Is it possible to perform somehow?

You can create a **factory with named constructors** in the dynamically loaded code. The factory would also implement a shared interface.

```
Class cFactory = ucl.loadClass("mypackage.MyFactory");
MyFactoryInterface factory = (MyFactoryInterface) cFactory.newInstance();     
MyInterface myObj = factory.makeOperation( );
```

Comment: Andy, thanks for the answer. How can I use that interface without putting it into my project? Because, technically, my code doesn't know my newly loaded class has implemented an interface named "MyInterface", right? My code won't be able to see that inteface when I declare it there. This loaded class was also dynamically compiled. And what was generated was just the .class file. I dynamically compiled 'Operation.java' and now I have in my folder 'Operation.java' and 'Operation.class'. I take Operation.class and I load it. But how can I take the interface 'MyInter' that Operation implements?

Comment: @AraújoFilho As you have declared the interface as you wrote `Operation` the interface has to be somewhere available else `Operation` shouldn't even compile. Usually (like in plug-in-able applications) there is an interface already present in the main code to allow invocation of dynamically loaded classes which have to at least implement the methods specified by the interface else it might get difficult to execute dynamically loaded classes per se

Comment: Thx @RomanVottner. I got it now. So, is there no way to dynamically load an interface?

Comment: @AraújoFilho An interface is like any other class in Java. It is loaded the same way also. Though, the interface itself is just a contract for any implementing class to contain a set of methods declared by that interface (if any) So, at runtime you do not really nead the interface but will have to look up the available methods on that object and invoke the one you need. In practice you use interfaces to avoid these reflection methods to retrieve methods, arguments and the like. By including the interface within the dynamically loaded code you do not gain any benefits IMO at least in dynamic CL

Comment: But if I don't have the interface added into my project I won't be able to dynamically compile that class. What I wanted was to dynamically compile it without needing the interface added into my project. Is that a way to, for example, dynamically load an interface like 'c/classes/MyInterface.class' and use it somehow in my project so that it can be able to compile Operation.java that implements MyInterface? I know how weird it should sounds...

Comment: @AraújoFilho - You can put the interface into a common library shared both by the loading and loaded code. If you want to call methods without reflection, you'll have to share an interface. If you used only reflection to interact through an expected API, you wouldn't get compile-time type-checking of the interaction API in both the loading and loaded code; leading to fragility and debugging costs.

Comment: But do you think is it possible to put that interface in a dynamically way? I will explain what I need: The loading take two files (Operation.java and MyInterface.java). The loading class dynamically compiles they both. Then, both generate .classes files. I wanna take Operation.class, dynamically instanciate it, and see the result of calling 'sum' method. But my loading cannot see that my newly loaded class 'Operation' has a method 'sum'. That´s why I was casting with an interface. But now the problem is how to use this interface without being into the project.

Comment: @AraújoFilho - Why do you need the interface to be compiled dynamically? Have you considered just compiling the class dynamically, with the already-compiled interface in the class path?